# How to reduce scale value of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an requirement to reduce the column value to `number(5)` from `number(6)`. For this i do not want to alter the column and instead just wanted to update the data using SQL query.

Example:

```
From      to
123456    12345
135790    13579
```

i.e. i just wanted to remove the last digit.

Comment: Do you literally want to trim off the last digit? Reduce it by a factor of 10?  Something else?

Comment: "alter the column" is different from changing the value anyway. What you requested can be done with `update [table_name] set [column_name] = trunc([column_name]/10)`. Are you 100% sure that is the BUSINESS requirement though? That sounds really strange.

Comment: Why would you do such thing? It seems to me this column should not be stored as a number, but as a `VARCHAR2` instead. You are treating these values as a strings.

Comment: What if the stored number has only 3 digits for example, do you still want to remove the last digit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to remove the last digit of a number, you can use :

```
floor(original_value/10)
```

If you want to remove the last digits only from numbers that have exactly 6 digits, you want :

```
decode(length(original_value), 6, floor(original_value/10), original_value)
```

Comment: @AlexPoole : you are absolutly right... I replaced `ROUND` with `FLOOR`